# Are last access time and location of connected devices recorded in iCloud?

Tags: forensics, ios, icloud

During a Forensic investigation, I parsed the sysdiagnose log file **/brctl/Brctl-dump.txt** and I discovered 50 devices connected to the same iCloud account.

Is it possible to retrieve from Apple the connection times and location to iCloud?

Comment: Does [this](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205064) serve your purpose?

Comment: No, I don't think there is a way to retrieve this: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8224503